# Fluttet sqfLite delete

Tags: sqlite, flutter, sql-delete

I am trying to build a note app. I watch some tutorials on sqflite in order to save data after the app is terminated. I have managed to save the data but i cant delete data.

Here is the DBelper class i have created:

```
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart' as sql;
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;
import 'package:sqflite/sqlite_api.dart';

class DBHelper {
  static Future<Database> databse() async {
    final dbPath = await sql.getDatabasesPath();
    return sql.openDatabase(path.join(dbPath, 'notes.db'),
        onCreate: (db, version) {
      return db.execute(
          'CREATE TABLE user_notes(id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT, text TEXT)');
    }, version: 1);
  }

  static Future<void> insert(String table, Map<String, Object> data) async {
    final db = await DBHelper.databse();
    db.insert(
      table,
      data,
    );
  }

  static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getData(String table) async {
    final db = await DBHelper.databse();
    return db.query(table);
  }
}
```

And this is how i save the data :

```
 onPressed: () {
                    Provider.of<Notes>(context, listen: false)
                        .addNote(newNoteTitle, newNoteText);
                    DBHelper.insert('user_notes',
                        {'title': newNoteTitle, 'text': newNoteText});
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
```

I have been trying to create the DBHelper.deleteNote but even if i manage to write some code without errors nothing gets deleted. Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to delete a note then you can use its `id`, something like this:

```
  deleteNote(String id) async {
    final db = await DBHelper.databse();
    db.delete('user_notes', where: 'id = ?', whereArgs: [id]);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment...my problem was that i wasnt creating the id...your code helped me a lot !!